# Button event listener always returns the same value

Tags: javascript, html, electron

preload.js

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  a = ""
  function add_chr(val){a=a+val;console.log(a,val)}
  for(var i of ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","+","-","*","/","."]){
    document.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click",()=>{add_chr(i)})
  } 
})
```

Example Buttons:

```
<td><button type="button" id="9">9</button></td>
<td><button type="button" id="8">8</button></td>
<td><button type="button" id="7">7</button></td>
```

My event listener set up in the for loop always passes "." to the add_char function no matter what button I click. Why does it only pass the last character present in the array?

Comment: That's because of the closures. Converting `var i of ....` to `let i of ....` will fix the issue.